# How to execute second test case if the first fails using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Supposing this is my code

```
Webdriver dr = new FireFoxdriver();

@test(prioity =1)
{
    dr.findelement(By.id("element1_id")).click();
}
@test(prioity =2)
{
    dr.findelement(By.id("element2_id")).click();
}
```

If `dr.findelement(By.id("element1_id")).click();` throws an exception then how **not** to stop execution of second test case afterward?

Comment: It should be `priority`, not `prioity`. Please edit your question and add the stacktrace.

Comment: Is this JUnit's Test annotation, or TestNG's Test annotation?  I think it's TestNG, but I want to make sure.  The question you're asking isn't a selenium question, it's a question about the testing framework you're using.  Also, the annotation you're using should be capitalized like `@Test`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TestNG, you can use the parameter alwaysRun.

```
@Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true)
```

This will execute the method regardless of what happens in any other tests (or configuration methods, so watch out!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of language you are using, but referring to your example it would be easily possible to combine your test cases - this is a java solution, which should also work with other languages:

```
WebElement element = null;
try{
   element = dr.findByElement(By.id("element1_id"));
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
  // If no matching element for "element1_id" is found, search for the other one
   element = dr.findByElement(By.id("element2_id"));
  // you might want to check again the exception
}
if(element != null){
   element.click();
}
```

Here is API Doc for the method findByElement and its return value/exceptions
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-

HTH